# Output redirection in Exchange Management Shell

Tags: powershell, exchange

I have some scripts being executed through scheduled tasks and would like to create logfiles for them.

The logfile should contain any warnings logged aswell, and I came up with this redirecting approach:

```
$ Write-Warning "I'm a warning!"
WARNING: I'm a warning!
$ Write-Warning "I'm a warning!" 3>$logfile
$ # warning text present in $logfile
```

This works as expected, but it does not work with modules imported by the Exchange Management Shell:

```
$ Set-Mailbox $mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true 3>$logfile
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'Path/to/$mailbox' have been modified.
$
```

`$logfile` remains empty.

Redirecting with `*>` or to `$null` doesn't have an effect either.

How can I capture these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the commands in an `Invoke-Command` using the `-Session` parameter and pass it the connected session variable [`$session`] to your Exchange Server while also using the `-WarningVariable` parameter.

Put the Exchange commands in a `-ScriptBlock { <Exchange commands> }` and you'll be able to capture any warning messages produced to pipe  over to `Out-File` saving to a log file.

### PowerShell

```
$warning = @();
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://exchangesrv.domain.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos;

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Mailbox $args[0] -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true;
    } -ArgumentList $mailbox -WarningVariable warning;


$warning | Out-File "c:\Logs\HiddenGALWarnings.txt" -Append;
```

**Note:** When trying `Set-Mailbox $mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true -WarningVariable $true`, you may get an error such as the below due to `RestrictedLanguage mode`

```
A variable that cannot be referenced in restricted language mode or a Data section is being referenced. Variables that can be referenced include the following: $PSCulture, $PSUICulture, 
$true, $false, and  $null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableReferenceNotSupportedInDataSection
    + PSComputerName        : exchangesrv.domain.com
```

#### Supporting Resources

- [New-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.3)

  > Creates a persistent connection to a local or remote computer.
- [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.3)

  > **`-Session`**
  >
  > Specifies an array of sessions in which this cmdlet runs the command.
  > Enter a variable that contains PSSession objects or a command that
  > creates or gets the PSSession objects, such as a `New-PSSession` or
  > `Get-PSSession` command.
  >
  > When you create a PSSession, PowerShell establishes a persistent
  > connection to the remote computer. Use a PSSession to run a series of
  > related commands that share data. To run a single command or a series
  > of unrelated commands, use the `ComputerName` parameter
- [Common Parameters](https://ss64.com/ps/common.html)

  > **`-WarningVariable`**
  >
  > Stores warnings about the command in the specified variable. All generated warnings are saved in the variable even if the warnings are
  > not displayed to the user.
  >
  > To append the warnings to the variable content, instead of replacing
  > any warnings that might already be stored there, type a plus sign (`+`)
  > before the variable name. `-WarningVariable +myvar`
- [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.3)
- [RestrictedLanguage mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes?view=powershell-7.3#restrictedlanguage-mode)
- [Powershell to Exchange 2013 - Restricted language mode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856240/powershell-to-exchange-2013-restricted-language-mode-error)
- [Exchange 2016 Powershell Command](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2303193-exchange-2016-powershell-command)
- [Using variables with Invoke-Command in Remote PowerShell sessions in Exchange Online](https://www.michev.info/blog/post/1687/using-variables-with-invoke-command-in-remote-powershell-sessions-in-exchange-online)

Comment: I got around to test it just now, and it works just as you explained - thank you!